Relaxing well-ordered sets
Consider the following definition:
We say that a totally ordered set $S$ is relaxed well-ordered if every subset $U$ of $S$ bounded below contains a minimal element (so a lower bound in $U$).
For instance, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is a relaxed well-ordered set; however, it is not well-ordered since it contains infinite decreasing sequences. I've been looking for literature concerning this notion, but I have not found anything yet. Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Why are you interested in this notion? Do you have some applications in mind, or some properties, or something? One can make up lots of definitions which haven't been considered because they don't come up in any natural way or don't have applications.

You haven't said what conditions on the ordering you do require. It's possible that the notion of a tree or a forest is what you are looking for, but how can we tell?

@LeeMosher Yes, I need such a property in studying generalized power series (as defined here) with exponents in a cancellative and torsion-free group.

I think every set of this form is either well-ordered or isomorphic to a set of the form $\sum_{k\in\omega^*} \alpha_k$, where $\sum$ is linear sum and each $\alpha_k$ is an ordinal. So they seem not much more complicated than ordinals.

The way I would word your property, is I would just say that every Subset of S with a lower Bound is well-ordered.

Properties like that are often associated with trees. Where we call well-ordered subsets of a linear order a branch of the tree
